# In Python debugger pydb, how can I set breakpoing in a function in another module?

Tags: python

I can use graphical debugger using -

`ddd --pydb script.py`

I can set breakpoints in current module or another module using -

`b filename:linenumber`.

But how can I set breakpoint at a function in "another" module?
(if it was in the current module I can just do `b funcname`)